# How to create a file .txt from a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `x_training` (size: 1000*2304) and another matrix `y_training` (size 1000*1) that contains labels of each instance in `x_training`. My goal is to create a file .txt that contain labels and `x_training`. Here is a little example for simplification :

```
x_training=[0.2 0.3
         0.5 0.4
         0.5 0.9]
y_training=[1
           2
           3]
```

so, the file.txt will contain :

```
   1  0.2 0.3
   2  0.5 0.4
   3  0.5 0.9
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x_training=[0.2 0.3; 0.5 0.4; 0.5 0.9]; % X
y_training=([1 2 3])';                  % Y - transposed       

data = [y_training,x_training];         % x and y concatenated
data = table(data);                     % data converted to table
writetable(data, 'file.txt');           % data saved as file.txt
```

Comment: please check this size of matrix 1000*2304 and 1000*1 !

Comment: It should work - please see below (I used ones and zeros as data): a = zeros(1000,2304);
b = ones(1000,1); 

 data = [b,a];
 data = table(data);
 writetable(data, 'file.txt');

Answer (score 3):

Its simple. Create a file (lets say OutPutFile.txt) in your MATLAB Current folder and run this script:

```
A = [y_training x_training];
B = A';

fileID = fopen('OutPutFile.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID, '%i %2.1f %2.1f \n',B);
fclose(fileID);
```

If you want to make a Tab-separated Values (TSV) file (which is openable in Excel), then modify the 2nd line to:

```
fprintf(fileID, '%i \t %2.1f \t %2.1f \n', B);
```

Comment: Might work, I'd suggest concatenating the two first, i.e. `fprintf(fileID, '%i %d %d\n',[y_training  x_training])` both saves you a line and makes sure of the line brake being used correctly.

Comment: @Adriaan But it doesn't work if user wants a TSV file if I am not wrong?

Comment: I have no idea what a TSV is, and the OP specifically asks for a txt, in which case this works fine

Comment: @Talha is dosen't work, wen I open the outputfile.txt I got this line    '1 2 3
2.000000e-01 5.000000e-01 5.000000e-01
3.000000e-01 4.000000e-01 9.000000e-01
'

Comment: @yosra I have fixed the format specifier (_assuming all your data is of 2 digits: 1 after decimal point_) Please check the updated answer and let me know how does it go

Comment: @TalhaIrfan it semms the same error, the file text contain this line : 1 2.0 3.0 
2.000000e-01 0.5 0.5 
3.000000e-01 0.4 0.9

Comment: @TalhaIrfan, yes it works, but does not the result that I want to obtain, your code poster the transpose matrix

Comment: `fprintf` works in *column order*, which is explicitly stated in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html). Always read the documentation...

Comment: @excaza Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

**FINAL EDIT**

You can create a matrix **data** of which the first column is of y_training and 2:end ,columns are x_training?

Please try and tell me if not working

```
data=[y_training x_training(:,1:2304)] %based on your matrix
fId = fopen( 'your file.txt', 'w' ) ;
 fprintf( fId, '%i %2.1f %2.1f \r\n', data(:) ) ; % update this line
 fclose( fId ) ;
```

As i have not your matrixes that why here is the demo of **testing** this code

```
    x_training=rand(1000,2304); % creating randomly 1000*2304 matrix as x_training
y_training=rand(1000,1); % creating randomly 1000*1 matrix as y_training
test=[y_training x_training(:,1:end)];
data=test;
fId = fopen( 'your file.txt', 'w' ) ;
 fprintf( fId, '%i %2.1f %2.1f \r\n', data(:) ) ;
 fclose( fId ) ;
```

**Alternate method**:

if above code not give desire output, update this

```
data=[y_training x_training(:,1:2304)] %based on your matrix
dlmwrite('myFile.txt', data);
```

Check it and tell me which one is fine code.

Comment: @ Muhammad I got this error Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in Untitled (line 8)
data=[y_training x_training]

Comment: @yosra  , the use of ` r `is compactable with windows systems. Please find my **final edit**, testing of this code and results of text files ..

Comment: @yosra if after **final edit** of this code, output do not looks as you want. Then just commented on lines belows then data and use this  `dlmwrite('myFile.txt', data); ` after the data in my code. Tell me which one giving you correct output?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative method

```
dlmwrite('testtext2.txt',['x_training  y_training'] ,'delimiter','') 
A(:,1) = y_training
A(:,2:3) = x_training
dlmwrite('testtext2.txt',[A],'-append','delimiter','\t','roffset',1)
```

Comment: your code is not providing solution of query, size of x_training and y_training , should be consider in this answer.

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem The OP didnt mention that he has to query the the matrices from  a text file , what the point of reading a matrix from a text file and then again saving it ,He has clearly written these both are matrices